# Keeping two folders in sync with rsync

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

I have two external drives. One of the drives is named "drive2" and it contains a folder named "Music." This folder has the following structure:

```
drive2/
    /Music/
           Pink Floyd/
                      1982 - Album Name/
                                        01 - Track.flac
                                        02 - Track2.flac
                                        and so on..
```

So, because of the folder hierarchy I guess I need a recursive sync.

I need the entire `Music` folder from drive2 to be copied to drive1. I think I can use something like this:

```
rsync -av drive2/Music/ drive1/Music/
```

However, there are situations when I modify the metadata of certain songs. Those metadata modifications are small like changing the title of the  album, and those modification don't necessarily change the size of the FLAC files, but their md5 fingerprint definitely changes because of altering the metadata. Right?

I noticed that when I use `rsync -a`, the `rsync` utility notices the metadata changes of FLAC files on drive2 and updates the files on drive1 as well to be in sync. Only the changed files gets transferred, which is exactly the behaviour I want. It seems to me that the `-a (archive)` flag implies the `-u` which tells to only update changed files.

However, I'm curious when `rsync` transfers the files that got their metadata updated, does the old files get overwritten completely on drive1? I mean they are replaced completely? Are the old files removed before the new ones are copied?

Comment: You've misunderstood what `-u` does. It ensures that changes are applied only to files on the destination that are also older then those on the source. So if you have A copied to B. You then change A. A little later someone changes B. With the `-u` flag A will not overwrite B because B is newer than A, even though it's different to A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when rsync transfers the files that got their metadata updated, does the old files get overwritten completely on drive1?

Yes.  The default behavior is that the file currently on the destination is copied to a temporary location.  Then any necessary updates are done on that copy.  Once the update is complete, the copy is renamed to be the correct file and the previous one is deleted.

> Are the old files removed before the new ones are copied?

For an individual file that is being updated, the default is that the file is overwritten only after the copy/update is completed.

For files that are removed from the source, you can control whether such files are deleted before, during, or after the updates/transfers of data.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync converts the old file into the new file, and before this happens, the checksums of for chunks of both files would be known by the receiver.

[https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/rsync.html#toc6](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/rsync.html#toc6)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately, I didn't understand much from it because of the technical jargon used, however I think rsync is just as safe to use as using the Nautilus file manager to transfer files. Am I right? I think I shouldn't worry about the integrity of the files.

Comment: Yes, Rsync is a safe way to transfer files. It is good for your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` is a very good tool for backup and generally copying, even via a network, I would say much better than Nautilus.

But `rsync` is not straight-forward to set up for synchronizing, easier for backup. If you wish, you can try `unison`, which is a dedicated tool for synchronizing.

Comment: Thank you. I think `rsync -av --delete --progress source/ destination/` will be enough for my use-case. By using `--delete` option, the files and folders that are deleted in the source folder will get deleted on the destination drive folder as well so it's the closest to a full sync.

Comment: @ZoltanKing, Yes it is a good alternative. If you use hard links, you might consider `-H` too, fin order to avoid wasting drive space. Otherwise with symbolic links, it is good enough with `-a`, which is the standard.